# SQL - Multiple queries on same table

Tags: sql

I have the following table called `Tracking`:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+
| DeviceID | DeviceName | PageCount | JobType |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+
|        1 | Device1    |        22 | print   |
|        2 | Device2    |        43 | copy    |
|        1 | Device1    |        11 | copy    |
|        2 | Device2    |        15 | print   |
|        3 | Device3    |        65 | copy    |
|        4 | Device4    |         1 | copy    |
|        3 | Device3    |        17 | copy    |
|        2 | Device2    |       100 | copy    |
|        1 | Device1    |       632 | print   |
|        2 | Device2    |         2 | print   |
|        3 | Device3    |        57 | print   |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------+
```

I'm trying create an output query with total copy and print for each device, like this example:

```
+------------+------+-------+
| DeviceName | Copy | Print |
+------------+------+-------+
| Device1    |   11 |   654 |
| Device2    |  143 |    17 |
| Device3    |   82 |    57 |
| Device4    |    1 |     0 |
+------------+------+-------+
```

Can you give me a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: A hint would be 'group by'.

Comment: Please add what DB system you're using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think for this is:

```
SELECT DeviceName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN JobType = 'copy' THEN PageCount ELSE 0 END) AS Copy,
       SUM(CASE WHEN JobType = 'print' THEN PageCount ELSE 0 END) AS Print
FROM Tracking
GROUP BY DeviceName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is:
1. get sum of pageCount for copy
2. get sum of pageCount for print
3. join the two results

getting the sums is easy, just need to:

```
1) select DeviceName, sum(pageCount) as copy from Tracking where jobType = 'copy' group by deviceName

2) select DeviceName, sum(pageCount) as print from Tracking where jobType = 'print' group by deviceName
```

and joining them:

```
select A.deviceName, copy, print from 
(select DeviceName, sum(pageCount) as copy from Tracking 
where jobType = 'copy' group by deviceName) as A 
inner join
(select DeviceName, sum(pageCount) as print from Tracking 
where jobType = 'print' group by deviceName) as B
ON A.deviceName = B.deviceName
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Well not in three columns but

```
select DeviceName, JobType, sum(PageCount) as count 
from table  
group by DeviceName, JobType
```

Comment: not exactly the format he wanted, but the numbers will be right